# Error while parsing a time string

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to parse some time strings like this:

```
String time_string = "10:00 AM";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = format.parse(time_string);
    // Do something with 'date'
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Log.w("Time", e.toString());
}
```

But the parser is failing with the exception:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10:00 AM"`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AM/PM marker may not match that of your default `Locale` Try

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: That it. Thanks (have to wait 10 min to mark as correct). Just for curiosity, what other markers exist besides AM/PM? I've never seen any translation of them.

Comment: The full list of `DateFormat` pattern component can be found in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). For fun looking up current `Locale` date format component values take a look at [DateFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html)